# Rails: Using filepicker with paperclip installed

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, paperclip, filepicker.io

I am using paperclip to upload photos in my rails app. Recently i came across filepicker and want to integrate it in my app.

As I am already using paperclip, will install filepicker gem create any issue? I am not getting are their performances dependent or independent.

Can anyone tell me, if i can use filepicker with paperclip installed or need to remove it before using filepicker?

Comment: They work independently so there shouldn't be any issues.

Comment: just be careful with filenames with spaces in them, as paperclip change the filename.  I have been getting issues with the paperclip processing resetting the files to 0 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

if you use gem filepicker-rails
You can attached image to paperclip by saving image from filepicker_url

```
self.image = URI.parse(filepicker_url)
```

Only with paperclip >= 3.1.4 though